# How to Fix error ls2j : threw java.lang class not found exception in lotus script?

Tags: lotusscript, domino-designer-eclipse

here is my code

```
Dim jSession As JAVASESSION
Dim jClass As JAVACLASS
Dim jObject As JavaObject

Set jSession = New JAVASESSION()
Set jClass = jSession.Getclass("JavaAgentReporter")

Set jObject = jClass.CreateObject
Call jObject.myMethod()
```

and I am invoking this onClick of ana action button

Comment: Try using the fully-qualified name for your JavaAgentReporter class (including package name).

Comment: unfortunately it is not working also

Comment: please delete this question as your same question is resolved here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61453149/2065611

Comment: kindly tell me where is delete option ?