# How to fix it class not found exception in domino designer?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript, domino-designer-eclipse, ls2j

here is my code when I trigger it it shows an error

```
Dim jSession As New JavaSession
Dim jClass As JavaClass
Dim jObject As JavaObject
Set jClass = jSession.Getclass("learn/MyClass")
Set jObject = jClass.CreateObject
Call jObject.myMethod()
```

The error is : Ls2j error : Threw java.lang class not found exeption 
I have tried everything which I found on internet but error is still there with package name without package name class path or loaction but somehow its not finding the class kindly help me out of this.

[image: thats the image of error]

Comment: Try with learn.MyClass

Comment: facing same error bro

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Fix error ls2j : threw java.lang class not found exception in lotus script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61437425/how-to-fix-error-ls2j-threw-java-lang-class-not-found-exception-in-lotus-scrip)

Comment: Where are the classes located?  In  .jar or as a class in the database?  If it's in a jar, where is the jar located in the file system?

Comment: classes are located in same database .nsf file there is no jar file

Comment: no @RichardSchwartz it did't reslove my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your Java class(es) into a ScriptLibrary of type Java

**[image: strong text]**

and refer to it with

```
Use "MyJavaLib"
```

in your LotusScript code.

Unfortunately, you can't just put Java classes into nsf's folder "Code/Java". This folder is reserved for XPages application development only.

Comment: hi Hermann I have a problem whenever  am trying to refer my library (Use "MyLib") it crashes my apllication with a notification error .. It worked for me but now m getting this error when i remove use "MyLib" application works fine

Comment: Sign the database and try it again, please.

Comment: Another possibility is that your Java code throws an Exception. Try to start with a simple Java code and add your original code one by one later.

Comment: thanks it is resolved..please look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61519697/how-to-access-current-logged-in-user-email-address-in-lotus-script/61521324#61521324

Comment: Oh, I see. You tried to use Domino classes in LS2J. This is not possible.